# Java and Intellij IDEA: check that method is called only once during request

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

I have some service and method which execution is very expensive. This method has no arguments and returns the same value if it's invoked from the context of same HTTP request.

So, I want to verify that this method is called only once during HTTP request and result is reused. The code base is a large enough so it's hard to verify it's manually.
I would like to have some inspection or action in IntelliJ IDEA that verified it.

So, naive approach for this is the following:

- Find usage of this method (this is already implemented in IDEA)
- Build call hierarchy for every usage(this is also implemented)
- For every entry in hierarchy check that there is no common ancestor with other entries (this is a thing I'm looking for)

Comment: If you are using Spring, you could use a request-scoped bean to cache the result (so only call the method if cache is null).  https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html

Comment: Yeah, good idea, this will help to improve performance. 
But before making any changes I would like to analyze usage and create some kind of report. So, I still need a way to find an issue before fixing it :)

Comment: Sorry, I can’t think of anything that does a “for every entry in the hierarchy”.  Also, even if there was, that would be a less than ideal solution, since in 6 months Time somebody refractors or adds another method call - chances are they won’t run that check.  However, making the function itself check the cache result will be a long-lasting consistent solution.

Comment: Yes, that's true - somebode can introduce issue again. And that's why I'm asking about a fast way to check multiple calls, since in future there may be another slow function. And if I suspect, that this fuction is called multiple time - I want to have a quick solution for that. Now I found not idea solution, but suitable for my current needs. But inspection in IDEA would be better :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it:

1. Generate Call Hierarchy (Ctrl + Alt + H) for desired method
2. Expand all nodes
3. Export to text file
4. Use any service to find duplicate lines

If you find duplicate - it means that some different method calls has common ancestor(and this is place that should be optimized)